k-PATH problem is in NL
I'm studying computational complexity at university and my professor showed us the ${\tt k-PATH}$ problem claiming that it is in ${\tt NL}$. The $k-{\tt PATH}$ problem was defined as
$$k-{\tt PATH} = \langle G, s, t, k\rangle  $$
where $G = (V, E)$ is a graph, $s \in V$, $t \in V$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and there is a $k$ path (meaning a chain in the graph passing through any vertex at most once with length $k$ edges) from $s$ to $t$.
As far as I know, the only way to prove that $k-{\tt PATH} \in{\tt NL}$ is to find a nondeterministic Turing machine that recognizes the language in $\log$ space or find a $\log$ space verifier with a read-once input tape for the certificate.
The professor solved it with a verifier that iterprets the certificate $c$ as the list of nodes from $s$ to $t$. What the verifier does is:

check that the certificate actually contains nodes
check that the nodes listed in $c$ are different from one another and the first is $s$ and the last is $t$
check that the nodes represent a valid path in $G$

This proof seems wrong. How can this verifier with a read-once input tape check if there are duplicate vertices in $c$ without having to scan it twice? If this needs to be done, the certificate needs to be copied to the work tape hence occupying more than $\log n$ space.
Having supposed that this proof is wrong, I thought I could try to find a nondeterministic Turing machine that works in $\log$ space and recognizes the language. After a couple of attempts, I wasn't able to reach the right space compexity.
So I was wandering whether k-PATH was really in ${\tt NL}$. Does anybody know?
Thank you in advance, for your answers and your time!

You haven't said what $n$ is.  Shouldn't it be $O(|V|^2)$ for the maximum number of edges (with unrestricted alphabet on the tape) or $O(|V|^2 \mathrm{lg} |V|)$ bits (for ${0,1}$ alphabet)?  Since no vertex appears twice on the path, $k+1 \in O(1)$ (bits: $k+1 \mathrm{lg}|V| \in O(\mathrm{lg}|V|)$) time is used to copy the vertex numbers to the tape...

@Eric_Towers $n$ is presumably the size of the input in bits, as always in complexity. Whether you use an adjacency list or adjacency matrix representation doesn't matter as they are interconvertible in logspace.

Regarding the problem at hand, the proof indeed looks flawed, and this problem is NP-complete by an easy reduction from Hamiltonian path, so unlikely to be in NL.
